# How can I ensure PF handler running from allocated stack using IST feature

Tags: x86, intel, stack-memory, uefi

I have done the changes in UEFI SMM code for PF interrupt that can be use known good stack using Intel IST feature.

But not sure how to ensure that SMM PF handler is executing/using  in know good stack when system hit page fault in SMM mode.

I would appreciate any help on this regard.

Answer (score 1):

SMM is intended to be a strict secure/isolated environment where the only memory it uses is in a special "SMRAM" space that can't be accessed from outside of SMM.

This means the SMRAM also contains private page tables (the only page tables that SMM code should ever use), and if there's a page fault it means that your SMM code is a buggy design failure and/or is corrupted by malware and/or the hardware is faulty; and for any possible case the correct response is to refuse to execute any code (by not having any page fault handler and letting the CPU triple fault/reset).

In other words, you should never need to care if the PF handler's stack is safe because you should never have a PF handler to begin with.